# Workspace Cycling With Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Or Mouse Wheel On Windows

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop, workspace

Many Linux distro desktops cycle workspaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd>s. Yet virtual desktops for Windows seem to only allow switching by indicating desktops by number. Is there a way to cycle with hot keys including the arrows or mouse wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the virtual desktops manager you are using. In [Finestra Virtual Desktops](http://vdm.codeplex.com/), you can change to a desktop by pressing Windows+Desktop Number. To switch to the next/previous desktop, you use Windows+Up/Left Arrow for previous and Windows+Down/Right Arrow for next.

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling us what Virtual Desktop Software you are using on Windows. With [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/) you can set your own hot keys. So if you want to cycle through the desktops you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Arrow Key</kbd>'s. On default it is set as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd>or the number of the desktop you want.